# How to draw signature with lines on iPhone screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl, quartz-graphics, paint

I want to let user draw a signature on iPhone screen, so I add a subclass of UIView and add some code to its 'touchesMoved' method.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    firstTouch = [touch locationInView:self];

    CGSize mySize = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mySize);                                    
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();                       

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);                                                
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1, 0, 0, 1);                              
    CGContextAddRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 5));                          
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);                                                 

    UIImage *redRect = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();         
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();                                            

    UIImageView *redRectView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:redRect]; 
    redRectView.center = CGPointMake(firstTouch.x, firstTouch.y);                               
    [self addSubview:redRectView];                                      

}
```

I'm drawing it with small rectangles and it turns out to be dot by dot. As it is too ugly, I want to draw the signature with lines. But how to distinguish firstTouch and lastTouch? If I only use 'touchesMoved' method, I can only get one touch point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/), you will also need to implement
`– touchesBegan:withEvent:` and
`– touchesEnded:withEvent:`.
After you implement these methods, you should be able to get enough data to implement a pathing bezier curve or other suitable solution.

[**edit**] A perhaps better solution would to be to obtain the touches directly from the `UIEvent` object once your controller receives a
`– touchesMoved:withEvent:`
notification.  Also, the [GLPaint sample code](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GLPaint/index.html) may also prove helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As the GLPaint sample code may be too complicated for beginners, I find [this tutorial](http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024). It is simple to learn for most beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a signature written with one's finger is going to be different than one written with a writing instrument.  You may want to re-think what you're using the signature for, and whether it's as binding as you need it to be.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. The signature is just used as an additional function for my app. It won't be the only way to identify a user.