# How to draw a letter or shape like square, circle in iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, svg, uibezierpath

I am developing an iPad Game to teach child how to draw Alphabet, Number and shape. There is some feature  like LetterSchool app. In which child will draw "A". How can I draw "A" within a specific path means "A" start from top and draw down to left first then move back to top point and draw down to right. and then intersect both line in middle. I have searched something and I found it can be done using SVG and UIBezierPath. How do I draw in specific bezier path which will get by SVG. What is the best way to do this.

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6774412/2695503

Answer (score 0):

This github project might be helpfull to you:
You can see there how to get bezier path of single letter or string and then draw it.

https://github.com/ole/Animated-Paths

and here is a tutorial how to draw smooth lines using your hand:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_freehand-drawing/

After drawing you can compare drawn bezier path with the expected one.